# Erlang: Kill all processes running in background

Tags: process, erlang, kill

I started a process in the background using:

```
erl -s system start -detached
```

I need to kill the process. Is there a way to kill all processes that are running in the background?

I tried:

```
init:reboot()
```

Comment: OS processes or Erlang processes?

Comment: i thought he was talking of OS Processes. But someone downvoted my answer and provided no comment. Because he is starting the erlang VM in detached mode (as a daemon), it is not possible for him to interact with it to bring it down using `init:stop().` e.t.c. So why would someone think that my answer is not useful at all ? the question even stated `kill` erlang processes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to start another erlang console, attach from it to first one and do all necessary things to terminate it properly.

1. You need to know name of the target node. From your example node is started without any name, you can give it by adding flag `-name` `-sname` like this: `erl -sname node_1 -s system start -detached`
2. Start another node with different name: `erl -sname node_2`
3. Press `^G` (control G) on the terminal with `node_2`
4. Press `r` and type name of the first node: `node_1@localhost` (or whatever name it have)
5. Press `c`

`Eshell V5.10.1  (abort with ^G)

(node_2@localhost)1>

User switch command

 --> r 'node_1@localhost'

 --> c

Eshell V5.10.1  (abort with ^G)

(node_1@localhost)1>`

You shell see new prompt with name of the first node. Now all your commands will be executed on the first node. To terminate first node you could type `erlang:halt().`

Comment: The VM is started in `detached` mode so issuing these shell commands is impossible as the shell is not accessible. perhaps if he accesses it via a remote connected node using `rpc` module.

Comment: it is not depends on "-detached" flag. You could connect to node if distributed mode is on. Try to do what i described.

Answer (score 13):

if you want to kill all running erlang processes on your system, probably run this as super user if possible. In the bash shell:

```
for i in `ps -ef | grep erl | awk '{print $2}'`; do echo $i; kill -9 $i; done
```

Comment: why the under voting ? i thought he was talking of OS processes , that is how i perceived the question. Whoever down voted this ought to put an explanation/comment so that future readers are advised accordingly.

Comment: Sorry, this is mine vote. Even if we are talking about OS process, with such script you could easily kill other erlang instances on same machine.

Comment: i thought the question had the keyword `all` ? probably my english has a problem, but i think the question was talking of all processes.

Comment: Shorter way to do this: `pgrep erl | xargs kill -9` :)